# How do i embed my java game into my webpage

Tags: java, html, applet

I designed a game using java and i want to embed it into a webpage using  but my code is not displaying the game.help with the correct code to embed the java game.

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<applet code="Dice.class" archive="Dice.java" width=200 height=200></applet> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried on the Java side? Have you implemented all proper Applet interfaces?

Comment: thanks but i have already fixed it.

Comment: You can also add your own solution here and accept it as an answer so that others will be able to benefit from it.

Comment: Yes, please, post how did you solve it.